# How do you make a function in Solidity that is only visible if condition is met in web3?

Tags: solidity

How does one make a function in Solidity that you can only call if a requirement is met outside the smartcontract (e.g. web3)?

Comment: `that is only visible` is different from `that you can only call`. Please specify your question.

Comment: And what does "a requirement is met **outside the smart contract**" mean? Maybe you should give a concrete example.

Comment: @criplingtrader check my ans.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer and sorry for the ambiguity of my question. Like Frolov said, I don't mean making functions public or private (because if a function is private, than it can get executed outside of the contract. To my understanding, every function that is public in solidity can be called by anyone (via web3, MEW, ...). So if I, for example, only want users to call a function if they guessed a right number (in javascript), how do I make a function that can only be called if that requirement is met?

Comment: I guess you could send some data with a transaction, but that doesnt seem like a good solution to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, there is no direct keyword to protect method as per condition, but you can do same task in two ways. First let me explain in brief about function access specifiers. Then I'll explain how to archive your requirements. Solidity will support 4 direct access specifiers:

1. private: If you declare a function as private that means function can call only with in the contract. Its not visible outside of contract. This is useful for internal operations/logic.
2. internal: If you declare a function as internal that means function, this function can access by derived contract. Refer below code:

> ```
> contract A{
>      function add2(uint msg) internal returns(uint){
>          return num+2;
>      }
> }
>
>
> contract B is A{
>   function addDefault(uint val) public returns(uint){
>        return add2(val);
>    }
> }
> ```

only contracts which extends contract A, can access add2() function. If you create an object for contract a you can't call add2(). If you declare add2 as a private you can't

3. external: If you declare a method as a external, you can't call this method directly. Using contract object only you can able to call. some people will say you can call functions locally also. But you should use this.() for call the method internal purpose.
4. public: private+internal+external is `pubic`.

**Now coming to your qus:**

1. Create a  modifier, implement logic and mention before access specifiers. When some one call the function EVM will first check access is visible or then (int shot) it will check your access modifier is matching logic will execute your code. Otherwise it will fail.

> ```
>  contract EmpCheck{   
>     private mapping(address,bool) private emps;
>
>         function getSalary() onlyEmp public returns (uint){
>             return 100;   
>         }
>
>     modifier onlyEmp(){
>      require(emps[msg.sender] == true);
>      -;   
>     } 
> }
> ```

Above example getSalary() will be visible to every one, only active emp's can actually get 100;

2. Directly call `require(emps[msg.sender] == true);` in getSalary() first line. Both are correct way.

But I'll recommend 1 approach. Because of code reusable and readability.

Comment: @criplingtrader, Let me know any qus.